# Windows batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, ping, traceroute

I am writing a batch file for some work where I need to check if the hosts are reachable or not. I need to log all the error codes I receive on execution of the commands I perform.

Specifically, I need to use ping, traceroute and arp command. But I do not find various error levels for executing these commands. Where can I find error levels or error codes for such windows commands ?

Also, is it better to use pathping instead of ping and traceroute separately?

Answer (score 1):

Batch solution with %ERRORLEVEL%

```
@Echo off
SET LOGFILE=MyLogFile.log
call :Logit >> %LOGFILE% 
exit /b 0

:Logit
:: PING 192.168.1.1 -n 1 | FIND /I /V "unreachable" | FIND /I "Reply from "
```

It basically redirects the output of the `:Logit` method to the `LOGFILE`. The `exit` command is to ensure the batch exits after executing `:Logit`.

---

Here's a PowerShell solution with a simple try-catch

```
Try {
    # Try to reach host 
    Test-Connection -Source "Server02", "Server12", "localhost" -ComputerName "Server01"    
}

Catch {

    # Catch the exception

    $_ | Out-File C:\errors.txt -Append

    # You can use this too but not both

    $exception = $_.Exception.Message
    Out-File -FilePath 'C:\myscript.log' -Append -InputObject $exception
}
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7757525/8303093) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587539/checking-host-reachability-on-windows-command-line) SO questions.

---

<sup>PowerShell</sup>

[Microsoft doc about Test-Connection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-6)

[Error handling in PowerShell](https://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell)

Comment: I am looking for batch file, not powershell.

Comment: Both of batch and ps1 are Windows native, can you specify your environment?

Comment: I need to use batch.

Comment: Thank you for editing the answer, but I do not ask for code. I am asking where can I find the possible errors for such windows commands? Let it be with powershell's Test-Connection or Batch's Ping.

Comment: @tech_enthusiast It should be store in errorlevel or %ERRORLEVEL% if he can't find errorlevel [about %ERRORLEVEL%](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-3-return-codes.html)